# HTML.Textbox validate a string entered in a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, razor

Is there a way to validate the information entered in this text box code -

```
@Html.TextBox(string.Format("Customer.CustomerMeasurementProfiles[{0}].CustomerMeasurements[{1}].Value", i, k), oMeasurement.Value, new { @class = "form-control input-sm " })
```

I want to check if it is blank or null, if so I want to put a 0 in the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need a 2 step solution. The first one would be handling the onchange event of your text box in client-side JavaScript. It is not bulletproof, as any client-side behavior can be spoofed/overridden. The next step would be checking/setting the submitted value in your controller code.